# How to filter content?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am setting up a property page with advanced custom fields and custom post types. I need to be able to filter the properties by number of bedrooms, price, location etc. I have been able to filter the properties by number of bedrooms but I cannot figure out how to apply two filters at the same time. For example I created a acf field called test and it has the values; one, two and three. Now I want to display a property that has 5 bedrooms and a test value of three. How can I change my code to do this?

```
$GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] = array( 
'field_1'   => 'bedrooms', 
'field_2'   => 'test',
);

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ){
// bail early if is in admin
if( is_admin() ){
    return;
} 

// get meta query
$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ) {
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'property' ) {
        if( isset($_GET[ $name ]) ){
            $value = explode(',', $_GET[ $name ]);

            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'        => $name,
                'value'      => $value,
                'compare'    => 'IN',
            );
        }
    }
}

// update meta query
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

return;
}
```

Comment: bedroom is also custom fields ?

Comment: @AnandChoudhary yes all of the values I want to filter by are in a acf field I have 7 in total 3 which are text fields and 4 which are select fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly run these query in your templates files where you want to display your custom posts. you can also add more fields after relation AND in defaults variable .

```php
<?php 

$defaults = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'category' => 0, 'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC', 'include' => array(),
    'exclude' => array(),'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
    'meta_key','meta_value',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
    'key'     => 'custom_field_name1',
    'value'   => $custom_field_value1,
    ),
    array(
    'key'     => 'custom_field_name2',
    'value'   => $custom_field_name2,
    )
));

$query = get_posts($defaults);
?>
```